# MySQL - On weekly update trigger that copies tables

Tags: mysql, triggers, eventtrigger

I have 6 database tables which all together present projects and processes are assigned to each project. Also users are assigned to each process. Here are the tables:

```
User
Project
Process
Proc_leader
Proc_checker
Proc_staff
```

What I want is to make system copy and store copied tables in database each Sunday. Some kind of trigger which will copy all data each Sunday and then will allow user to view saved records based on date. For example:

I have 1 project with 1 process. And 3 users assigned to process as process leader, process checker and process staff.

When it come to Sunday System should copy tables and create copied tables with name

```
User06/11/16
Project06/11/16
Process06/11/16
Proc_leader06/11/16
Proc_checker06/11/16
Proc_staff06/11/16
```

Or something like this. Then user should be able to press `View History` button and system will show something like this:

```
Show Records for 23/10/16
Show Records for 30/10/16
Show Records for 06/11/16
```

And it should display data from that table.

I am not so experienced in sql and have not enough knowledge to put this in practice. So I am looking for any help. Any ideas how can I achieve this? Thanks

Comment: [tag:mysql] and [tag:sql-server] are two completely different products. It's rare that *both* tags should be applied to a single question. Which product are you using?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever i am using mysql, thanks for notice. I removed sql-server tag

Comment: But left it in the title

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to write a cron job . with below steps

```
1 create table [like][1] master table ( Append date with name) . 

2 Create sql for inserting record form master tables to New tables created at step 1 http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-select.html.
```

Schedule the cron job as per your requirement.

Answer (score 1):

Triggers will not help you in this, what you need is [SQL Agent Job](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlagent/2010/10/14/creating-a-regularly-scheduled-job/).

You need to schedule the job for every Sunday.

Before that, create query to copy your table to a new table like below

```
select * into NewTable from ExistingTable
```

As you require the new table name to be dynamic i.e. with date, you may need create [dynamic sql](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx).

Comment: Unfortunately, OP has now clarified that this is a [tag:mysql] question.